# Python, socket. or no socket (Debugging help)

Tags: python, sockets

Still figuring out this python stuff. I have been messing around with a pinger protocol. It is not completed yet quite as I want, but it is on it's way.

> mySocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, icmp)
>   AttributeError: type object '_socketobject' has no attribute 'socket'

This is the error I am getting, and the problems seem to exist totally in "doOnePing". I will also add the complete code below this incase anyone was wondering what was going on everywhere else. I am using

> from socket import *

Thank you for your help.

```
def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):

    icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")

    try:
        mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, icmp)
    except error, (errno,msg):
        if errno == 1:
            msg = msg +(" - ICMP messages can only be sent when running as root")
            raise error(msg)
        raise

    myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF  # Return the current process i

    sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
    delay = receiveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)

    mySocket.close()
    return delay
```

Complete Code

```
from socket import *
import os
import sys
import struct
import time
import select
import binascii

ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST = 8


def checksum(str):
    csum = 0
    countTo = (len(str) / 2) * 2

    count = 0
    while count < countTo:
        thisVal = ord(str[count + 1]) * 256 + ord(str[count])
        csum = csum + thisVal
        csum = csum & 0xffffffffL
        count = count + 2

    if countTo < len(str):
        csum = csum + ord(str[len(str) - 1])
        csum = csum & 0xffffffffL

    csum = (csum >> 16) + (csum & 0xffff)
    csum = csum + (csum >> 16)
    answer = ~csum
    answer = answer & 0xffff
    answer = answer >> 8 | (answer << 8 & 0xff00)
    return answer


def receiveOnePing(mySocket, ID, timeout, destAddr):
    timeLeft = timeout

    while 1:
        startedSelect = time.time()
        whatReady = select.select([mySocket], [], [], timeLeft)
        howLongInSelect = (time.time() - startedSelect)
        if whatReady[0] == []:  # Timeout
            return "Request timed out."

        timeReceived = time.time()
        recPacket, addr = mySocket.recvfrom(1024)

        # Fill in start
        icmpHeader = recPacket[20:28]
        type, code, checksum, packetID, sequence = struct.unpack("bbHHh", icmpHeader)

        if packetID == ID:
                bytesInDouble = struct.calcsize("d")
                timeSent = struct.unpack("d", recPacket[28:28 + bytesInDouble])[0]
                return timeReceived-timeSent

        timeLeft = timeLeft - howLongInSelect
        if timeLeft <= 0:
            return "Request timed out."


def sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, ID):
    # Header is type (8), code (8), checksum (16), id (16), sequence (16)

    myChecksum = 0
    # Make a dummy header with a 0 checksum
    # struct -- Interpret strings as packed binary data
    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    data = struct.pack("d", time.time())
    # Calculate the checksum on the data and the dummy header.
    myChecksum = checksum(header + data)

    # Get the right checksum, and put in the header
    if sys.platform == 'darwin':
        # Convert 16-bit integers from host to network  byte order
        myChecksum = htons(myChecksum) & 0xffff
    else:
        myChecksum = htons(myChecksum)

    header = struct.pack("bbHHh", ICMP_ECHO_REQUEST, 0, myChecksum, ID, 1)
    packet = header + data

    mySocket.sendto(packet, (destAddr, 1))  # AF_INET address must be tuple, not str


# Both LISTS and TUPLES consist of a number of objects
# which can be referenced by their position number within the object.

def doOnePing(destAddr, timeout):

    icmp = getprotobyname("icmp")

    try:
        mySocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, icmp)
    except error, (errno,msg):
        if errno == 1:
            msg = msg +(" - ICMP messages can only be sent when running as root")
            raise error(msg)
        raise

    myID = os.getpid() & 0xFFFF  # Return the current process i

    sendOnePing(mySocket, destAddr, myID)
    delay = receiveOnePing(mySocket, myID, timeout, destAddr)

    mySocket.close()
    return delay
def ping(host, timeout=1):
    # timeout=1 means: If one second goes by without a reply from the server,
    # the client assumes that either the client's ping or the server's pong is lost
    dest = gethostbyname(host)
    print "Pinging " + dest + " using Python:"
    print ""

# Fill in start

    count = 100
    for i in xrange(count):
        delay = doOnePing(host, timeout)

        if delay == None:
            print "failed. (timeout within %ssec.)" % timeout
        else:
            delay = delay * 1000
            print "get ping in %0.4fms" % delay
    print

# Send 100 ping requests to a server separated by approximately one second.
# Report the minimum, maximum, and average RTTs at the end of all pings from the client.
# In addition, calculate the packet loss rate (in percentage).



ping("google.com")
```

UPDATE:
Thank for the help. I removed the socket. when I created my socket, now I am getting the error

> ```
> _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
> ```
>
> socket.error: [Errno 41] Protocol wrong type for socket

Comment: The documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.getprotobyname suggests you only need to be using socket.getprotobyname if you're using socket.SOCK_RAW instead of socket.SOCK_STREAM. I'd try stripping out the getprotobyname business, and if that doesn't work, changing SOCK_STEAM to SOCK_RAW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `from socket import *` to `import socket`

When you do `from socket import *`, `socket.socket` will shadow the package with the same package named `socket`. It's in general better to be specific about what you are importing.

Comment: @TheCrownedPixel Would you please also update your complete code making the error?

Comment: Had to change the socket.socket to just socket. Also had to SOCK_STREAM to SOCK_RAW when using "from socket import *"

Answer (score 0):

You've imported the class `socket` into your namespace without the module prefix, but you're trying to access it with the module prefix when you do `socket.socket` in `doOnePing`.

For the record, you should be skeptical about `from <module> import *` imports, because when you use them you're no longer explicit about what's in your namespace.